# Console window output should print in html file in table format

Tags: html

I am working in a application where i have to copy the output data present in console window and that should save in html file as table format .can any one help me ???

Comment: cann't you put your output in html table like a way you are showing your output in consoole window, if you are displaying object or else ??

Comment: OK is there any way to save the output in html file with table formate

Comment: can you show your code to display your output in console?

Comment: Name         City           Age
kumar        banglore       24 
vijay        banglore       24
ajay         chennai        24
ravi         banglore       24
kumar        hyd            24
kumar        banglore       24
kumar        banglore       24
kumar        banglore       24

Comment: that out put should come line by line according to that related data in html is possible to save ???